# find all the points like $x_0\in \mathbb R$ such that $Df(x_0):\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is a linear isomorphism

Tags: derivatives, linear-transformations

The question is given as below:
For $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ with the formula $f(x)=x^3$, find all the points like $x_0\in \mathbb R$ such that $Df(x_0):\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is a linear isomorphism.

What i did:
$Df:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ such that $Df(x)=3x^2$
If we put $x_0$ instead of $x$, The result is a number... not a function that i prove it to be a linear isomorphism.  What am i seeing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, $Df(x_0)$ is a linear map from $\mathbb R$ into itself. More precisely, it is the product by $f'(x_0)$. Therefore, it is an isomorphism if and only if $f'(x_0)\neq0$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer... What do you mean by "the product by $f'(x_0)$?

Comment: I mean the function from $\mathbb R$ into itself deined by $x\mapsto f'(x_0)\times x$.$

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful if you use notation of a higher dimensional derivative for a one dimensional function.

The value $f'(x_0)$ is the same as the partial derivative $\frac{d}{dx}f(x_0)$ and because of just one dimension your linear map $Df(x_0)$ is defined as
$$
Df(x_0):\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},~Df(x_0)[v]=\frac{d}{dx}f(x_0)v=f'(x_0)v.
$$
Obviously it can be an isomorphism if and only if $f'(x_0)\neq 0$ which holds if and only if $x_0\neq 0$.